# In Authorizers Lambda only context 401 "Unauthorized" can to pass Gateway Response?

Tags: aws-lambda, lambda-authorizer

I'm trying to pass type: new Error("Expired Token") from Authorizers Lambda to Gateway Response but it not work.
I just can pass type: new Error("Unauthorized").
But I have three case:

- Missing Authentication Token
- Unauthorized
- Expired Token

I try to use custom with: {"message":"$context.authorizer.messageText"}. But case not run to it "Missing Authentication Token".
Anyone have solution for it?
help me please!